# Slick2D and TileD

Tags: java, tiles, lwjgl, slick, eclipse

I've been learning Java for a while, and with my aims of being a game developer later in life, I've came across Slick2D+lwjgl and following tutorials and making some little things. However; I don't have a clue what to do when it comes to the tileD maps. here's what I've done so far; I've made my map and it's called map.tmx and it has collision objects in it, how do I get my code to run this map and the sprite to "interact" with it.
Thanks for any help :)

Edit: I got it rendered onto the program... but how can I make the sprite stop on
some platforms I've made? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create polygons to check for collisions and check them every step in updating the position. I found example in the internet and try translate comments to English.
You can [download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/TileMap.zip) example.

Other way is creating collision map, like [this](http://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/using-slick-2d-to-write-a-game/)

P.S. Sorry for Google-translate.